# Connect Apache httpd to Tomcat on the same computer without using mod_jk

Tags: tomcat, httpd.conf, mod-jk

Currently I have a server with Apache httpd and Tomcat installed. Both are connected by mod_jk.

Tomcat folder

```
tomcat9
|-webapp
   |- frontend1
   |- frontend2
   |- backend
```

Httpd config

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile /usr/share/tomcat9/conf/workers.properties
... 
JkMount /backend   app_worker
JkMount /backend/*   app_worker
JkMount /frontend   app_worker
JkMount /frontend/*   app_worker
JkMount /frontend   app_worker
JkMount /frontend/*   app_worker
```

/usr/share/tomcat9/conf/workers.properties

```
worker.list=app_worker
worker.app_worker.type=ajp13
worker.app_worker.host=localhost
worker.app_worker.port=8009
worker.app_worker.lbfactor=50
```

This time I want to run on a new server. However, since I only install it on 1 server, I don't want to use mod_jk for load balancing anymore.

The front-end I intend to put in Apache httpd, and the back-end is in Tomcat. Plus I want to use only AJP.

How do I set up Apache and Tomcat?

Comment: The provided configuration shows that you are using a single tomcat (worker.app_worker.host=localhost). are you facing any error ?

Comment: @Pandurang Yeah you're right. There is only 1 single tomcat.
The problem is that it is not good to have front-end and back-end in Tomcat together.
Furthermore I don't want to use mod_jk anymore. It's inconvenient if every time I change the front-end (add a new one or remove) the mod_jk has to be fixed again.

Comment: Then you can use mod-cluster. In this, you don't need to add anything at the Apache httpd level. Even you can add more servers without any configuration change at the Apache httpd level.